# Exception in code from Xcode duplicated target

Tags: xcode, exception, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, target

Got a bit of a quandary which attaches to the following code

```swift
        var returnCell = PlanetDataCell()
        if let dequeuedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlanetDataCell", for: indexPath) as? PlanetDataCell {
            returnCell = dequeuedCell
        }
```

I have a project/target this works in. **I duplicated the target and in the duplicate target this throws an exception.** While there is now code change between the two targets around LaunchScreen and Main. This code is buried fairly deeply and has not been touched at all between the two versions.

```
[<UICollectionViewCell 0x7fab4637c370> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key moreInfoButton.
```

The PlanetDataCell is defined in storyboard not in a separate xib or by code. As pictured below.

I've tried cleaning the build folder (on both targets) disconnecting the action for the button that connects to moreInfoButton: and reconnecting it. I have also blown away DerivedData and that changed nothing.

[image: Cell design and composition]
[image: moreInfo Button connections]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the module was being automatically assigned to the original target. I had to trigger a rarely used setting (for me) in IB where the Module is inherited from the target. Pictured below.

[image]

Comment: What does "was being autos to the original target" mean?

Comment: @matt corrected the text. Must have been a typo. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Makes this q-and-a a lot more potentially useful! :)

Comment: Might be duplicate or at least related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109900/interface-builder-inherit-module-from-target-picking-wrong-target